# SQL Take a Min of a sub-query with a constraint

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have two Tables A and B, and columns a (in A) and b (in B). These columns have the same values but are different names. Column c in table A has int values. I want to update column d in table B such that:

Each entry in column D is the min of the entries in C that have matching values in a and b.

I wrote this query:

```
Update B
Set d = min(select A.c From A where A.a = B.b) 
From A, B
```

But this is an error because I can't run aggregate functions in sub queries. I've looked up how to do this but I can't understand it. Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min` cannot be used in where clause. However, it can be used in subquery used in where clause. Try the below query. It should do the trick for you.

```
Update B
Set d = (select min(A.c) From A where A.a = B.b)
```